# How to identify the position where a spin wheel stopped?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a spin wheel on my website that has eight equal sections, each with a different color. When the user clicks a button, the wheel spins and eventually stops at a random position. I want to be able to detect which position the wheel has stopped at, so that I can perform some actions based on that.

I have tried modifying the JavaScript code to detect the position, but so far it has not worked. Can someone help me fix the code so that it correctly identifies the position where the wheel has stopped?

Here is the current HTML and CSS code for the spin wheel, along with the JavaScript code that I have tried:

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let btn = document.getElementById("spin");

btn.onclick = function() {
  let deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
  container.style.transition = "all 10s ease-out";
  container.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    container.style.transition = "none";
    let actualDeg = deg % 360;
    container.style.transform = `rotate(${actualDeg}deg)`;
  }, 10000);
};

function spin() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
  const spinButton = document.getElementById('spin');
  const slices = document.querySelectorAll('.container div');

  let deg = Math.floor(5000 + Math.random() * 5000);

  spinButton.style.pointerEvents = 'none';

  container.style.transition = 'all 5s ease-out';
  container.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;

  let winningSlice = slices[Math.floor(deg % 360 / (360 / slices.length))];
  let winningColor = window.getComputedStyle(winningSlice).backgroundColor;

  setTimeout(function() {
    spinButton.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
    arrow.style.borderColor = winningColor;
  }, 5000);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 15px solid #dde;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s;
}

.container div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 0);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  left: 135px;
}

.container .one {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  left: 50%;
}

.container .two {
  background-color: #ff9800;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container .three {
  background-color: #e91e63;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.container .four {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.container .five {
  background-color: #009688;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.container .six {
  background-color: #795548;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.container .seven {
  background-color: #9c27b0;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.container .eight {
  background-color: #f44336;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow::before {
  content: "\1F817";
  font-size: 50px;
}

#spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #a2a2a2;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button id="spin">Spin</button>
<span class="arrow"></span>
<div class="container">
  <div class="one" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="two" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
  <div class="three" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="four" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
  <div class="five" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="six" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
  <div class="seven" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="eight" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

I have tried implementing a JavaScript function that detects the position of the spin wheel using the CSS classes 'slice' and 'selected', but it does not seem to be working. I expected the function to alert me when the spin wheel lands on a specific position, such as 'position one' or 'position two'. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would appreciate any suggestions or advice on how to make it work. I need to know when the spin stops in 'verdade' ou 'desafio'.

Comment: I've used your code to create a demo of your problem within your question; if you could [edit] the question to include the (relevant) CSS that might help us to answer you.

Comment: You already have the position calculated. It's `deg` and the slice it lands on is `winningSlice`. What else do you want?

Comment: All you need to do is define the `slices` -- `slices = ['verdade','desafio','verdade','desafio','verdade','desafio','verdade','desafio',]`

Comment: This is why math in school is very important. It is 100% untrue that you will never use it again.

Comment: I added the css. I tried to calculate the deg and rotation to know where the spin stopped but it didnt work

Comment: @JohnMcRow have you tried calling your `spin()` function? ;)

Comment: i tested your code in a codepen. and it doesn't show any problem. and the function spin() already provided the winningslice. you can just add some css style to show it. 
here is the code link https://codepen.io/essenken/pen/oNPdNYB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
let btn = document.getElementById("spin");

btn.onclick = function() {
  let deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
  container.style.transition = "all 10s ease-out";
  container.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`;
  setTimeout(() => {
    container.style.transition = "none";
    let actualDeg = deg % 360;
    container.style.transform = `rotate(${actualDeg}deg)`;

    let winningSlice = getWinningSlice(actualDeg);
    if (winningSlice) {
      let winningValue = winningSlice.dataset.value;
      alert(`The spin wheel has stopped at ${winningValue}`);
    }
  }, 10000);
};

function getWinningSlice(degrees) {
  let slices = document.querySelectorAll(".container div");
  let sliceAngle = 360 / slices.length;
  let sliceIndex = Math.floor(degrees / sliceAngle);
  return slices[sliceIndex];
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 15px solid #dde;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 5s;
}

.container div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 50% 100%, 0 0);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  left: 135px;
}

.container .one {
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  left: 50%;
}

.container .two {
  background-color: #ff9800;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.container .three {
  background-color: #e91e63;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.container .four {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.container .five {
  background-color: #009688;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.container .six {
  background-color: #795548;
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.container .seven {
  background-color: #9c27b0;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.container .eight {
  background-color: #f44336;
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #fff;
}

.arrow::before {
  content: "\1F817";
  font-size: 50px;
}

#spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #a2a2a2;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button id="spin">Spin</button>
<span class="arrow"></span>
<div class="container">
  <div class="one" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="two" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
  <div class="three" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="four" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
  <div class="five" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="six" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
  <div class="seven" data-value="verdade">Verdade</div>
  <div class="eight" data-value="desafio">Desafio</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works when i run here, but when i add it to my code it does not work, im trying to fix that, thanks for helping!

Comment: I fixed the problem, now its working, thanks a lot!!